# How can I hide ends that have been woven in on a crochet project?

Tags: crocheting

I just recently finished my first crochet blanket, and when I was done I needed to weave all the ends in because I had switched colors quite a bit. Even though the finished product is done the ends stick out at various points even though they've been "weaved in". Is there a technique to getting ends hidden in a "finished" way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First it is important to leave a long enough tails so that you have enough to weave in.

I usually just use a plastic needle and work inside and out of stitches to try and wrap around yarn. In the places where I know part of the ends are to be seen you would try to force those on the bottom of the work or where people wont see (like the inside of a hat.) Working into where your row ends also works since it is usually visually different anyway.

I would not weave in one loop at a time but try to pull many stitches close together and try to work the tail into all of them at once. Once I am sure I have covered enough ground I would relax the work and that will pull the tail back into the piece. Then after you might just need to either tuck in that last tuft or cut it off it need be.

Assuming this is something that you want to wash and is made of washable material then you can put this through and it should stay together. Not forever obviously but it won't fall apart instantly if done right.

Comment: Ok so weaving ends down the end of rows (in something like a blanket or scarf) would hide the ends better then weaving them across a row?

Comment: I put them across rows often. My row stops are usually tighter and I can't fit much in there. Honestly most people don't even notice. Keep the tail as loose as the stitches so you don't see a taught line or anything. Wrapping is important to stop it from unraveling. Changing directions when weaving helps.

Comment: Ok thanks! This gives me some great new things to try! (ps I know I'm not supposed to put in thank you comments but I can't help myself)

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide the ends of the yarn, make sure that when you're tucking the ends in with a yarn needle, you're not only going through once, but back-stitching it as well, which will lock it in place.  Then just carefully cut the end very close to your work, and it should never come unraveled.